# Get the Value from Prompt in the input text

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I want the value user enter in the Prompt shows in the input text field id="myName"

```js
var a = prompt("Enter your name");
document.getElementById("myName").innerHTML.value = a;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myName">
```

Comment: You should remove `innerHTML`: `document.getElementById("myName").value = a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use **innerHTML** here, just change the property **value**.

```js
var a = prompt("Enter your name");
document.getElementById("myName").value = a;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myName">
```